# Iterate through S3 folder and compare images inside that folder?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

Hello I have a bucket in s3 which contains a folder that has images that I need to iterate over. While iterating through each image I need to compare the iterated image with another to display similarities.

How would I go about iterating through the files in the folder of the bucket? I have already written a method to compare the images I just need to be able to iterate through the folder.

Answer (score 1):

Boto3 is the official aws sdk for python. You would want to do something like this:

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource(service_name='s3', aws_access_key_id=XXXXXXXXXXX, aws_secret_access_key=XXXXXXXXX)
bucket = s3.Bucket(BUCKET_NAME_AS_STRING)
for obj in bucket.objects.all():
    #if you need to download image for comparison
    bucket.download_file(obj.key, LOCAL_FILE_PATH_DESTINATION)
```

and then you can run your image comparison.

Answer (score 0):

[s3fs](https://pypi.org/project/s3fs/) is a good library that allows you to do that easily

You create a S3FileSystem object with your prameters and then can call ls() or glob() with the `s3://<bucket>/<key>` path and iterate over the results.
For more concrete examples you can look at their [documentations](https://s3fs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)
Here's a basic example:

```
>>> import s3fs
>>> fs = s3fs.S3FileSystem(anon=True)
>>> fs.ls('my-bucket')
['my-file.txt', 'another-file.txt']
```